# How to access constructor variables into the methods with in the same class in c#

Tags: c#

Here is my code.i am not able to access constuctor value in the function.

```
 public partial class ForgotPassword : UserControl
    {
         private string mobile_num2 = "";
         public ForgotPassword(string _mobile_num)
         {

             mobile_num2 =_mobile_num;
             MessageBox.Show(mobile_num2);//Getting Value here
             InitializeComponent();

         }

       private void btn_submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
            string val_conf_pwd;
            string conf_pwd = txt_new_conf_pwd.Password;
            val_conf_pwd = c.validate_conf_Password(pwd, conf_pwd);

            if (val_conf_pwd == "success")
            {
               MessageBox.Show(mobile_num2);//Getting Null Value Here
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is your actual code (and it's not just that you actually declared another *local* variable within your constructor instead of assigning the value to the field) then I suspect the problem is that the instance that `btn_submit_Click` is being invoked on isn't the same one as the one you're constructing with the non-null value.

So you need to look at where you're constructing any instances of `ForgotPassword` - you won't be able to just construct a new instance and hope that it will have the same `mobile_num2` value as an existing instance, unless you explicitly pass the right value to the constructor.

(As an aside, I'd encourage you to use more conventional names for methods and variables - just `camelCase` without underscores. But obviously that's not part of what's going wrong.

Comment: Jon look at `RoutedEventArgs` I hope this must me wpf `ASP.NET` dont have `RoutedEventArgs`. I may be wrong